# I get a weird glitch when trying to make an AI for a Pong paddle

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, slick2d, pong

I am making a pong game for MiniLD using Slick2d (and therefore java), but when I try to make the AI it is not gonna work. I get a paddle flickering between two positions. I need help. Here is the code I use.

```
static int maxSpeed = 3;

(...)

float ypos = ball.getCenterY() - (paddleCPU.getY() + maxSpeed);
paddleCPU.setY(ypos);
```

Comment: You need to show more code.

Comment: I think that is all that is needed. What do you want to see?

Comment: No, thanks. What I want really is to know how I can fix it. Although I think I have the answer now.

Comment: @pta2002 how you can fix it depends on how you want your AI to behave. Do you want it to be impossible to defeat? Do you want it to be random?

Comment: Random would be cool. I am gonna try to set `maxSpeed` to a random num between 0.6 and 1 every time the ball touches the paddle.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try actually limiting the rate of change of y to being between -maxSpeed and +maxSpeed:

```
float dy = ball.getCenterY() - paddleCPU.getY());
dy = Math.max(-maxSpeed, Math.min(maxSpeed, dy));
paddleCPU.setY(paddleCPU.getY() + dy);
```

Comment: Ithink that makes it unbeatable (for what I have tried, though I am terrble at pong so i cant really tell :P)

Comment: Nevermind, I set `maxSpeed` to 0.8 and now it works. Not too fast, but not too slow. Just perfect ;)

Comment: @pta2002 why not change the maxSpeed to a random number within a certain range.

Comment: Grat idea. I am gonna try that out.